Permissions error in directories used by Docker and application I am developing
I have run a docker container mysql from my own application development on C#, and configured data persistence to this path:
C:\ProgramData\Persistence\data\mysql
When i start everything goes well because there is no data (first run)

Once I start developing (create database... etc..) and for some reason I restart the PC and open again docker-desktop and starting the container, it no longer works...

I have managed to determine that the problem is the directory permissions, the read-only attribute (I'm still investigating why...):

I have investigated, and I have tried to solve it with the following methods:
from CMD: icacls "C:\ProgramData\Persistence" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T
form PowerShell: Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Persistence" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.Attributes -= "ReadOnly" }
These commands were executed with my personal user having active administrator privileges and running CMD and Powershell with administrator privileges.
but the problem persists... and I can't find a programmatic way or in YML file to solve it, which is my only interest...
Log Content:
2024-04-15 16:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
2024-04-15 16:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-04-15 16:31:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Permission denied
2024-04-15T16:31:39.941325Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-04-15T16:31:40.118455Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2024-04-15T16:31:40.123899Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.3.0) starting as process 1
2024-04-15T16:31:40.127250Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2024-04-15T16:31:40.128854Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-04-15T16:31:40.129566Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.3.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2024-04-15T16:31:40.129575Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.

I have verified that changing the shape attribute manually solves it, but it is not what I am looking for.
Update 1
i have try some changes on my YML file and docker file:
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./log/mysql:/var/log/mysql:rw

and
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/mysql
RUN chmod -R 0755 /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql /etc/mysql

My expectation is that something like this will work.
Update 2
I have been evaluating and for some reason the problem is related to how docker works and the directory structure... and the interaction with third-party software...
The problem occurs in the following way:

once docker is up for the first time with the containers and the mysql content everything goes well...
If by some chance another third-party software or tool uses or enters the path where the persistence data is located, these.
When you restart the system it stops working correctly. as if between the third party application and the restart something happened with the permissions... it sounds stupid but it seems that something happens at that moment.

this my PS Scrript
I would like to think that there is a way to solve the problem natively from the yml with which the structure and the docker/container environment are built, but so far I have not solved it... therefore I resort to working around the problem and every time this occurs, you need to manually run this script in powershell:
# Define the path to the directory
$directoryPath = "C:\ProgramData\Persistence"

# Get the current ACL (Access Control List) for the directory
$acl = Get-Acl $directoryPath

# Define the permission rule to grant full control to everyone
$permission = "Everyone", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"

# Create a new access rule
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission

# Add the access rule to the ACL
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)

# Set the ACL for the directory
Set-Acl -Path $directoryPath -AclObject $acl

# Check if the permissions were applied successfully
Get-Acl $directoryPath

So:
Although this script solves the problem once started/detected manually, it is not the way I expected to solve it, I am still looking for an alternative that prevents this situation.

WSL for awhile will run a separate instance as an Administrator than an non-elevated process. What user is starting the MySQL process and which user own the directory the process is attempting to use. The ProgramData “read only” flag is a red herring. So questions recommend running chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql

I'm not an expert on Docker, but from an UAC standpoint, what you encounter looks nominal to me. ProgramData is a system folder, and all subfolders and files will inherit its permissions. Which means that while any process can create files, a User has read-only access to such files. And once you terminate the process which has created a file, there will be no more "Owner/Creator" of such file: from that point onward, only an Admin (or the System) can modify such file.
So, you need an admin account which grants the necessary rights over your files  to the current user (or to all users). Usually, this is handled by an installer (which needs Admin permissions). But in your case, there is no installer, hence the need for the extra script.
Your first approach to handle this through Docker would need your container to run with Admin rights, which I believe usually is not the case.
If you want to avoid the need to change permissions, the way to go is to work outside the ProgramData folder: %AppData% is the right place for such things.
To find a solution from within Docker, the better place to ask would be on Stackowerflow

Related thread on Superuser
Related thread on Stackoverflow


The folder C:\ProgramData is not the best choice for a program
running in user-mode. As you can see, its permissions are:

While the Administrators group has full control, the Users group has
only read and execute permissions for this folder.
However, if you look at its subfolders, you will see a different
picture. Some of the subfolders give the Users group or the
current user full control, while others give only read and
execute permissions.
The reason for this difference is whether the user needs to write to
this subfolder or just read from it. The subfolder itself is created
by the installation program of the concerned product while executing
in elevated mode as administrator. The installation can allocate this
subfolder any permissions that are needed, and no more.
A user that operates in standard User mode cannot then go beyond
his intended permissions.
The solution for you is then to do what you have already done and
give your own subfolder the required permissions while executing
in administrator mode.
I strongly advice against modifying the permissions of the
C:\ProgramData folder, because changing the installation
parameters of Windows from those set by Microsoft
may cause problems in the long term.
Such a change will propagate to the other subfolders of the other products,
therefore undoing their protections as intended when their
installation programs created these subfolders.
